# Add class on modelform django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

How to dynamically add a class to a field on a modelForm.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields = ['type']
       widgets = {
           'type' : RadioSelect()
       }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['type'].widget.attrs.update( {'class':'radio-inline'})
```

I did the code above but it is not working for some reason. The class 'radio-inline' is not created on the template.

Comment: Your example code works for me, except for the indentation of `widgets` (it should be the same as `fields`). How are you using the form in the view?

Comment: I fixed the widgets indentation and made not difference. ``

Comment: There is how I use it in the view. 
 
`if request.method == "POST":
       form = MyForm(request.POST)`

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions I'm afraid. As I said, your example works for me.